# NSArrayController not picking up data merged from another context

Tags: macos, core-data

So, i have a simple table view and my column 'Name' is bound to NSArrayController. The NSArrayController is defined with Entity type and is going to hold Person objects. I have checked "Prepares content" in the XIB file. In my application, i create and insert a managed object called "Network". This class has delegate methods that handle data incoming from the network. When my updateNotificationMethod is  called, i create my Person managed object and insert it into the managed object context of "Network".

The above works like charm and i am able to display the names in the table view without any issues. However, if i handle the notifications in a thread that has a new managedObjectContext and i handle NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification in my main thread to merge the changes into my main managed object context, then i don't see any updates in my table view.
Shouldn't the NSArrayController be aware of the new managed objects merged and display those?

Any ideas on what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If you create "Network" on the main context and optain to it with [network objectID] in your background thread make sure you do a save before entering the background thread. Otherwise the objectID of "Network" will be temporary and lead at the end not to the correct object.
Everything else looks fine to me.